# SSRS 2005 using a class

Tags: reporting-services

I need to use a custom class that is stored in a dll assebly.  I have made a reference to the DLL under SSRS 2005 VS 2005 IDE  under Report/Report Properties/References  pointed  to DLL and added under Classes:

Fpl.PowerGeneration.WindProdIndicators.Data.Measurements.MeasurementFactory and Instance: MFactory

Under Report/Report Properties/Code I have

```
Function DisplayName(byVal PlantId As Integer,Mth As Integer,Yr As Integer) As String
   Dim m _factory as MFactory
   returnm _factory.GetMonthlyInfo(PlantId,Mth,Yr).Site.DisplayName()
End Function
```

When I build I receive

There is an error on line 1 of custom code: [BC30205] End of statement expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the MFactory instance, SSRS should be instantiating the object for you with the name MFactory. But your code seems to try to create an instance of MFactory class...which is an instance, not a class. Try dropping the Dim line and just using MFactory directly.

```
Function DisplayName(byVal PlantId As Integer,Mth As Integer,Yr As Integer) As String
    Return MFactory.GetMonthlyInfo(PlantId,Mth,Yr).Site.DisplayName()
End Function
```

Or better yet, just use `=MFactory.GetMonthlyInfo(PlantId,Mth,Yr).Site.DisplayName()` directly in the expression where it's needed.